# Xcode 10 GM: XCUIScreen.main.screenshot() crashes with `dyld: lazy symbol binding failed`

Tags: swift, xcode, testing, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

When I run `XCUIScreen.main.screenshot()` (in Xcode 10 GM) from an `XCTestCase` the test crashes with:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol _XCStringFromRect in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib/../../Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest because dependent dylib #12 could not be loaded
dyld: can't resolve symbol _XCStringFromRect in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/lib/../../Library/Frameworks/XCTest.framework/XCTest because dependent dylib #12 could not be loaded
```

Answer (score 2):

[Release notes](https://developer.apple.com/download/) says (`Known Issues in Xcode 10 – IDE`):

> Devices running iOS 12 may fail to take screenshots requested from Xcode’s Devices window.(42873539)
>
> **Workaround**: Take the screenshot on the device

I think it's all connected, it's known issue, so someday it will be fixed.